# Wpf datagrid don't refresh dynamic

Tags: wpf, multithreading, datagrid

I have the following code, where `TabResultadoBusqueda` is a `Datagrid`.

My problem is when I click in one button of this window , it's frozen until the operation finishes.

I would like that the user could be doing other things while `Datagrid` is loading, as the time to perform the operation is 1 min,.

Example code event `Click` in one `Button`:

```
 TabResultadoBusqueda.ItemsSource = null;
 TabResultadoBusqueda.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable<articuloPOCO>)cambioDeArticuloListaAArticuloPOCOlista(m.todosArticulosPAGINADOS(0, 50));

           TabResultadoBusqueda.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                     new Action(
                         () => aaaa1()
                                  )

                 );
```

code of aaaa1:

```
for (int j = 2; j < 15; j++)
        {
            ((List<articuloPOCO>)TabResultadoBusqueda.ItemsSource).AddRange((IEnumerable<articuloPOCO>)cambioDeArticuloListaAArticuloPOCOlista(m.todosArticulosPAGINADOS(j, 50)));
            TabResultadoBusqueda.Items.Refresh();

        }
```

Any help will be good.

Comment: AddRanges before you set the ItemsSource

Comment: can u write minimal example? i test and it does the same things.

Comment: Are you still using Dispatcher?

Comment: Why can't you add the ranges before you bind and not use dispatcher?

Answer (score 0):

Do your long running operation on a separate thread.  This will keep your UI thread unblocked and responsive.  It looks like a `BackgroundWorker` will be good for your situation.  Read about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx